# Save either a new or detached child object using Spring JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
class Parent{

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child")
    private Child child;
}
```

The child class and therefore the child table has no references to Parent. Now the problem is that I have code like:

```
//Brand new transient parent created
Parent parent = new Parent();
//Either find child in the DB using the attributes or create a brand new one
Child child = createOrFindChild(childAttributes)
//Set child in parent
parent.setChild();
parentRepository.save(parent)
```

The problem here is that if I don't find the child and try to save I get the error:
"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"

If I set CascadeType.PERSIST then it works when a brand new child but when I find the child in the DB and it is detached then I get the error:
"detached entity passed to persist".

Anyway to make it work without explicitly saving child first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CascadeType.MERGE and use `EntityManager#merge` in your repository.

Comment: doesn't work. Getting a object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing when saving a new object.

Comment: Please create a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue so that people can look into it then.

Comment: Adding ```CascadeType.MERGE``` will have no effect in the OP's presented case. When you try to save a transient entity using spring data jpa repository, the ```persist``` method (not ```merge```) is called with the parent instance as an argument. Since ```merge``` isn't called on the parent, there is no way it will be cascaded onto the child.